# Hyphen's writing problem

Tags: word-order

I'm new in this website so if my question is inappropriate, obviously tell me.. Sorry in advance :D

I'm writing a sentece and in this sentence there are two words that are near. These two words are: **self-esteem** and **group-esteem**.

Is it correct in English to put this words like this: self and group-esteem ?

(the complete sentence is: The process of comparison is automatic when there is a categorial distinction whose aim is the increase of self and group-esteem)

Thank you! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use hyphens appropriately when listing multiple hyphenated terms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113422/how-to-use-hyphens-appropriately-when-listing-multiple-hyphenated-terms) Also [Can one use a hyphen to form 2 words with same prefix?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332732/)

Comment: Your question *title* here probably won't help any future visitors find the answer to this type of question, but the site search facilities also index the question text, so it's always useful to have multiple questions about the same thing (if someone ends up looking at this, they'll be easily able to follow the link to what will hopefully be a satisfactory answer). Anyway, don't feel bad that you didn't find an earlier question - I *knew* it existed, but it still wasn't easy for me to find it!